# JPA: Delete children in OneToMany

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, children

I have a  OneToMany mapping as below

Parent:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = parent, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Child> childs = new ArrayList<Child>();
```

Child:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parentid")
private Parent parent;
```

While updating the Parent entity,  I am getting an exception:

```
A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance
```

My code:

```
parent.getChild().clear();
parent.setChild(childList)
```

Answer (score 1):

You remove the children from the parent, but as `Child` is the owning side, you have to remove the reference to the `Parent` from the `Child` entities.

```
for (Child child: children) {
   child.setParent(null);
}
```